# Using the capture from begin in the text between in tmLanguage

Tags: visual-studio-code, grammar, tmlanguage

[image]

I am trying to color my language like this, where the loop variable in detected from the variable name in the ?myFor and subsequently colored in the body of the for loop.

My grammar looks like this for now where I am able to detect begin and end using ?myFor and ?endMyFor. But I can't seem to understand how I can use the capture group from the begin's capture for the rest of the body.

```
<key>begin</key>
            <string>\s*\\?myFor\s?\((.*)\s*=.?,\s*(.*)(<=|<|>|>=|=|==|!=).*,\s*(.*)(\+=|=|-|-=|\*)</string>
            <key>beginCaptures</key>
            <dict>
                <key>1</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>support.variable.generic.a</string>
                </dict>
                <key>2</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>support.variable.generic.a</string>
                </dict>
                <key>4</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>support.variable.generic.a</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>end</key>
            <string>\?endMyFor</string>
```

Comment: you only want to color the loopvar in the loop block? use semantic coloring in the language server

Comment: Is there a way to do it using tmgrammer though?

Comment: TM Grammer is stateless, you can assign scopes to capture groups, after that the regex match is gone